# html img tag within button tag not picking up javascript applied to button tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, button, web-frontend

I have a dynamic formset where the user can click a button to remove forms from the formset before clicking submit. I've achieved this by applying some javascript to the button tag. This is a django app.

My issue arises when I add a trash can icon as the button's image. The image itself is not clickable and dynamic (i.e. removing the form when clicked), but the button area around the image is. I would like the entire thing to be clickable.

When trying to click the trash icon itself, nothing happens, and the console logs this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'checked') at HTMLButtonElement.removeIngredient`

When tracing this error, I encounter the following in the chrome console sources tab:

[This image corresponds with the javascript below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSJqJ.png)

HTML

```
<button class="remove-button" id="remove-ingredient" type="submit"><img src="{% static 'inventory/trash-icon.png' %}"></button>
```

CSS

```
.remove-button  {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.remove-button img {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.remove-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Javascript

```
    function removeBtnListener () {
        const removeIngredientBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('remove-button')
        
        for (let i = 0; i < removeIngredientBtns.length; i++) {
            removeIngredientBtns[i].addEventListener('click', removeIngredient)
        }
    }
    
    function removeIngredient (event) {
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault()
        }
        
        let ingredientFormToBeRemoved = event.path[1]
        let indexString = ingredientFormToBeRemoved.id
        let array = indexString.split('-')
        let indexNum = array[2]
        let deleteCheckbox = document.getElementById(`id_ingredientquantity_set-${indexNum}-DELETE`)
        deleteCheckbox.checked = true
        ingredientFormToBeRemoved.setAttribute('class', 'hidden')
    }
```

[Here is an image of the formset. By clicking the area around the trash can icon (red outline), the form is removed. By clicking the trash can icon itself (green arrow), nothing happens.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1jmY.png)

Does anyone know how to make this work so the entire element removes the form properly when clicked?

Comment: @Bravo thanks for your reply. the HTMLButtonElement.removeIngredient is referring to the removeIngredient javascript function I applied to the button html element. Does that make it more clear?

Comment: `deleteCheckbox` is null... Double check if `indexNum` is the expected value.... Feels like it should be `let indexNum = array[1]`.

Comment: hi @Bravo - i could be mistaken, but I believe HTMLButtonElement is chrome console's standard way of referring to an "html button element". In this case, I have applied the function "removeIngredient" to a <button> element. I think chrome console is referring to that as HTMLButtonElement. See the docs here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement). I know the javascript is working on the button itself b/c I can remove a form from the formset, just not when I'm clicking the image itself. Could be wrong here! I'm a beginner! :)

Comment: Hi @LouysPatriceBessette thank you! `array` is just the html id of a to-be-removed form split into an array format. An element with `id="ingredient-form-3"` would have an array of `ingredient,form,3`. I pull the number "3" by doing `array[2]`. I need this to check the right delete checkbox element so my database updates correctly. It think this is working b/c the form removal works when I click the `button` element, but not the `img` element. Any ideas? I'm pretty stumped here. Alternatively, I could set the background image of the button to be the trashcan, but running into issues there too